# Hide border is the scrollbar apears just in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my div block I have an 1px border and I want to disable it when the scrollbar appears. Can I do this just using CSS?

```
<div class='a'></div>

.a {
overflow-y: auto;
border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

Something like:

```
if a.overflow-y is visible then a.border = 0
```

I am using react too.

Comment: Not reliably. Scrollbar styling works quite a bit in Chrome but less elsewhere (Firefox/Edge)

Comment: Nope, but you can add `overflow-y: scroll` so you always have the scroll.